# ArcPy Append GDB's

Tags: arcpy, append, error-000338

I have two GDB's that are the same schema. One is a master GDB that we are appending other individual GDB's into. The GDB's contain several points, polys, lines, and tables as well as 2 datasets with additional feature classes. I've started with a bit of code I found from https://community.esri.com/thread/105313#comments and modified the multiple GDB's to a single. The code appears to do what I want; append feature classes that are within the datasets to the master and append all root feature classes into the master.

When I run the script I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python27\Temp\append.py", line 20, in 
>       arcpy.Append_management(appendinput,GDBD+'/'+fcr,"TEST")
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 3995, in Append
>       raise e
>   ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>   ERROR 000338: Inputs must be either all Feature Classes, Tables or Rasters; not mixed.
>   Failed to execute (Append).

Since the code specifically lists only feature classes, I'm not sure where the mixed inputs is coming from as tables should not be included. How can I adjust this code? (I'm new to python and coding in general)

```
import arcpy  
from arcpy import env  
##Destination GDB  
GDBD="C:\Python27\Temp\GLOBAL_GEODATABASE.gdb"  
##List of Origin GDB  
GDBS="C:\Python27\Temp\UPRR_CaliforniaModel_20170130_1.gdb"  
##Set Environment  
arcpy.env.workspace=GDBD  
##Get List of FDS  
FDS=arcpy.ListDatasets()  
##Get List of Root Feature Classes  
ROOTFCS=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("","POLYGON")  

##Append elements in Root Feature Classes  
for fcr in ROOTFCS:  
    appendinput=[]  
    for FCI in GDBS:  
        appendinput.append(FCI+"/"+fcr)  
    ##print appendinput  
    arcpy.Append_management(appendinput,GDBD+'/'+fcr,"TEST")  

##Append elements of Feature Classes inside Feature Datasets  
for FD in FDS:  
    for FC in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*","POLYGON",FD):  
        appendinput2=[]  
        for FCI2 in GDBS:  
                appendinput2.append(FCI2+"/"+FC)  
        ##print appendinput2  
        arcpy.Append_management(appendinput2,GDBD+'/'+FC,"TEST")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script wants the variable `GDBS` to be a list. It's a string. This is causing parsing issues.

```
GDBD="C:\Python27\Temp\GLOBAL_GEODATABASE.gdb"
```

Strings can be parsed just like lists, one character at a time:

```
>>> for g in "ABC":
    print g


A
B
C
>>>
```

This is what is happening with the variable `GDBS` here:

```
for FCI in GDBS:  
    appendinput.append(FCI+"/"+fcr)
```

Change the string into a list.

```
>>> for g in ["ABC"]:
    print g


ABC
>>>
```

Or, in your case:

```
##List of Origin GDB  
GDBS= [r"C:\Python27\Temp\UPRR_CaliforniaModel_20170130_1.gdb"]
```

Note the `r` at the start of the string. This is a [raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals). File paths generally need the `r`.

```
GDBD=r"C:\Python27\Temp\GLOBAL_GEODATABASE.gdb"
```